# implement camera in my app using java script

Tags: html, camera

I am developing an HTML5 app in which I have to take pictures. Can anyone tel me how to implement camera feature in my application.
I am creating a mobile website.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WebRTC implementation](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/) to target the device's camera.

People from HTML5 Rocks have a great tutorial explaining how to implement it on your web app: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Could you please vote my answer, just in case this solution worked for you? Thanks, appreciate it.